# "Full Text" Email Searching EWS (Exchange 2010 SP1)

Tags: c#, search, exchangewebservices

Afternoon all,

I've hit a brick wall with Exchange searching using EWS 1.2 and was wondering if anyone could offer some insight.

I'm trying to remotely search a mailbox for keywords and am wanting to search the entire content of an email (subject, body, attachments etc). I found that you can use the  System.FullText canonical property to search all indexed fields which seems ideal (from here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/cebef229-c30e-49a6-a15c-ce1fbb46c46e).

However, I'm experiencing some weird issues - if I search a well known folder such as "Inbox", attachments are searched correctly. However if I use a search folder (All Items or a custom one I've created), attachments are not searched :(

My question sounds very similiar to the one posted in the link I referenced above but I've followed the suggestions there and the issue remains.

Any sort of suggestions or insight into this would be great!

Thanks alot,

Adam